# Jenkins Build Giving "No Module Named ______" when executing a shell script that executes another python3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins

I am trying to run a python3 script within a shell script (that is called by jenkins' build function).

The following is my pipeline script:

```
node {
sh label: '', script: '''#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/user/test.py'''}
```

in my python3 script I have 
`"import git"`

and a few more modules.

I have tested my python3 script without triggering it from Jenkins and it works. However if I try the "build" function on Jenkins it gives me `"No Module named ____"` error on all the modules I import in my python3.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: What user is running Jenkins on the system? Is it the same user that you tested manually? My guess is no. Since python modules can (and in most cases _should_) be installed per-user, it's not a good test to do this.

Comment: Regardless, you should write your automation to be more bulletproof than trusting that your Jenkins node is configured correctly. Baking in the expectation that python3 is available is probably fine, but running `sh script: 'pip install -r requirements.txt'` (along with a good requirements file) is a good idea regardless.

Comment: You can test this somewhat in a test pipeline that reads `node { sh 'whoami' }`, then logging in as that user on the box and running the test.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when pip installing a module for one user, by default it won't allow other users to access that module.

uninstalling the module, then setting "umask 022" before re-running the pip install solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python is very sensitive about it's environment. It usually runs in what are called 
*virtualenv*.

This means in the environment you are running your code, Python has created the environment. While you are running it in Jenkins, you need to re-download the modules for the environment you are running.

Have a look at the documentation for more info: [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with virtual environments.

Comment: Something like this happened to me a couple days ago and creating a new environment helped me solve it. So i thought this was the same case.